# Need help regarding Git Hard reset

Tags: git

By mistake I did git hard reset & my repository moved to 10 days older commit. Got following message

`WARNING: The push did not contain any new commits, but force pushed to delete the commits and changes below`.

Now I am trying to bring it a particular version using following commands.

```
git reset f8c41200a6094dd2fe5952bcd40e6f47accc5642
fatal: Could not parse object 'f8c41200a6094dd2fe5952bcd40e6f47accc5642'.

git checkout f8c41200a6094dd2fe5952bcd40e6f47accc5642
fatal: reference is not a tree: f8c41200a6094dd2fe5952bcd40e6f47accc5642
```

Not sure how to fix this. Tried deleting local copy and got fresh from repository still not working.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: after moving to 10 days old commit by `git reset <hash> --hard`, did you `git push origin master --force`? From your warning message, it seems you have made a forced push, which erased the git history. If this is the case, then your commits will be overridden.

Comment: Pro-tip: You basically never-ever-ever want to use `push --force` unless you fully understand the ramifications. `push --force` is one of those few things that can actually destroy a repo irretrievably if done wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Use `git reflog` to find the commit-id of the commit you were on previously, then you can `git reset --hard` back to that commit.

Note that, if you are pushing/pulling from a remote repository, you'll need to pull or fetch the remote commits before you can `reset` to them - `git reset` only understands commit-ids that are present in your local repository.

Comment: git reflog is showing ten days old commit because my repo is hard reset to older version.

Comment: @Kalava: In my repos, `git reflog` shows me when I reset, rebase, merge or checkout. Check all the entries. If your `reflog` is only showing one entry, then something else has happened - maybe you're using a new working copy?

Comment: yeah after i reset , revert was not working. So i deleted local files & cloned from repository.

Comment: Can you please specify the entire list of operations you performed in your question? It seems you've done more than just `reset --hard` - there seems to have been a push, a clone, maybe more? You might be totally screwed if you did `push --force`, `rm -rf repo` and `git clone` - now neither remote or local will have the new commits.

Comment: just noticed "Tried deleting local copy and got fresh from repository still not working." from question, so unless, you also pushed up the changes you want, you cannot revert.

Comment: These are my list of operations 1) push --force 2) git reset --hard(went to 10 days old version) . Now stuck very badly.

Comment: But you also said you deleted your local files. Did you delete your local repo too? Also, did you `push --force` before or after `reset --hard`?

Comment: 1) push --force 2) git reset 3) deleted local files(repository) 4) git pull

Comment: So, if you did your reset *after* your push, then how is it that your new repository is still set to the old commits?

Comment: Even I am unclear on that. Sorry may be i missed an operation since I was trying different options. But my team mate has local copy of latest version. How can i just replace remote repo with his local repository copy.

Comment: Have him push to the repo, then you can pull.

Answer (score 0):

Your [git-reflog](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) is going to come in real handy here. Basically run `git reflog` it will print out something like:

```
0f22a58 HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to HEAD~2
0244eb7 HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from new_branch to master
d11f540 HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from master to new_branch
```

If you want to reset back to `HEAD@{2}`, run: `git reset --hard HEAD@{2}`

If you have already deleted your local repository, you won't have a reflog, and will have to use the log of the repository.

If you force pushed up to a remote, then you will need someone else's repository to force push newer changes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. git reflog is showing ten days old commit because my repo is hard reset to older version

Comment: Reflog does not work like that, it will show the `hard reset` as long as it is still the same working copy, if you already deleted that working copy, then you are out of luck with reflog. `1a75c1d... HEAD@{0}: reset --hard HEAD^: updating HEAD`

Answer (score 0):

> By mistake I did git hard reset [...] Tried deleting local copy [...]

So, you had local commits that were not pushed elsewhere, and you deleted your local repository. If I understand correctly, then most likely you deleted your data in an irreversible manner. There might be hope if:

- ... you still have a backup copy of the repository in which you did the `git reset --hard`, then your data might still be there. If so, then 1) make another backup copy before anything else, and 2) see the other answers.
- ... the reflog is enabled on the server. But by default it's not (`git init --bare` does not activate it), and depending on which server it is, you may not have access to it anyway.